# Continues beam deflection

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, beam

does any one know how to derive the deflection equation of a continues beam of three span of equal length and equal UDL load
Here's [a link](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/11413/29978)

[image: the image shows the question]

---

[these two pictures shows my tries to solve the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0PcR.png)

[image: picture 2]

Comment: Do a search on here or google , here is one that may be relevant: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/11413/10902

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: @Wasabi, I have tries to solve it by my self but I got confused. the question is to find the deflection at the middle of the span. the deflection of the upper continues beam

Comment: @FatmaAlsatmi: I understand. However, we need you to show us what you've tried so far so that we can best understand what you're actually having trouble with. Is it in calculating the reactions? The internal force equations? Please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and exactly where you got confused.

Comment: @Wasabi, I have edited my question.
thank you for responding I really appreciate it
thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deflection Formula for Continous Beam](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11413/deflection-formula-for-continous-beam)

Comment: Hi @Andrew, yeah it answers partially. I am asking about the double integration to find deflection at mid span of the beam but the this shows the maximum deflection. Thank you